# How to pass query parameters to different pages after performing a search?

Tags: asp.net, sql

When I do a search on my site the results are displayed in a repeater with a hyperlink to a page that displays more information about the record. I am using the below code to transfer the information to my more descriptive Table 1 page:

```
   <ItemTemplate>
        <li>

 <a href="<%# ResolveClientUrl("~/table1InfoPage.aspx?id=" + Eval("idTable1").ToString()  + "&descriptionTable1=" + Server.UrlEncode(Eval("descriptionTable1").ToString())
       <p class="Test"> <%# Server.HtmlEncode(Eval("descriptionTable1").ToString())%></a></p> 

       </li>
   </ItemTemplate>
```

This works when selecting a result for my first table. However, I am searching and displaying results for two tables, with the second one using 'idTable2' and 'nameTable2' columns. My question is how can I pass parameters based on two tables? I want it so when I perform a search, it differentiates between the different ID's and columns of the two tables, and then transfer to the appropriate descriptive page when I click a record.

Comment: Why do you need 2 pages? Keep a single page and display from it different description based on passed parameters